# Unable to create MVC View using scaffolding in Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate Update 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, visual-studio-2013

I recently applied Update 5 to Visual Studio 2013 (Ultimate Edition) running on Windows 8.1. After the update, any time I try to create a Razor View (*.cshtml) file in my MVC application using scaffolding, I get the following error:

> There was an error running the selected code generator:
>
> The Templates\PackageVersion5.1.3.xml file is missing from the
>   installed template folder

[image]

From the error, it is clear that some file (`PackageVersion5.1.3.xml`) is missing but I'm not sure how to fix it. I even repaired Visual Studio but to no avail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As yoo probably know during scaffolding your view is generated base on this missing xml file. I don't know why your file is not there but you can copy it from one of your colleagues computer or reinstall visual studio.

Maybe you have change something i VS options?

Comment: Thanks Marcin for your prompt response. I like the idea of getting this file from my colleague. Let me give it a try and see if it works.

Comment: You, Sir, are a genius!!! Thank you so much! I copied the file from my colleague's computer and it worked like a charm! Thanks again.

Comment: why my colleague says he didn't find this file using windows search on whole computer...

Comment: I recently converted from MVC3 to MVC5, same solution folder.  I'm still having this issue except it's asking for "PackageVersions5.0.2.xml", unfortunately work won't let me copy/paste in ProgramFiles.  I can get our helpdesk to do it though, from what directories exactly to we copy *to*?

I have no issue's with scaffolding/generation on new solution.  (Desperately I am generating on that solution and pasting code to my other, older solution!!!) My suspicion is that  there is some configuration in the project folder/file somewhere that's pointing to MVC3 xml.

Answer (score 0):

I avoid the scaffolding options in Visual Studio.

Why? In my experience, the standard MVC pattern where everything separated by type will always led to a difficult to manage and test solution.

Instead, I now prefer to organise MVC projects by feature (http://timgthomas.com/2013/10/feature-folders-in-asp-net-mvc/).

Comment: @GauravMantri I know this doesn't answer your question, however thought it would be helpful advice.

Comment: I agree with you. It's just a convenience factor. In fact in all of my projects, I use this feature to create an empty cshtml file.

Comment: Great. I was hesitant to submit the answer. Have you heard of http://yeoman.io/? It is a command line template generator. I've started using it as a way to create file groups.